# divisores propios de un numero en JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Hola amigos tengo un problema con un ejercicio que me mandaron en clase es el siguiente:

Un número deficiente es todo número natural que cumple que la suma de sus divisores
propios es menor que el propio número. Por ejemplo, 16 es un número deficiente ya que
sus divisores propios son 1, 2, 4 y 8 y se cumple que 1+2+4+8=15, que es menor que 16.
Programa una función que pasado un número por argumento devuelva True si es
deficiente y False si no lo es.

Quiero saber si es posible que planteamiento logico utilizariais o si hay alguna funcion en javascript que te saque dichos numeros por los que es divisible.

```js
    var introduce = prompt("Escribe un número");
    var numeros;

    for (numeros=2;numeros < introduce/2; numeros++) {
        if (introduce % numeros === 0) {
            console.log(numeros," lo divide ");
        }
    }
```

De momento se como hallar los divisores propios en consola, pero me falta saber como coger esos valores y sumarlos. Para saber si son menores que el propio numero que fue introducido, me de un false o un true.

Gracias.

Comment: var introduce = prompt("Escribe un número");

var numeros;
for (numeros=2;numeros < introduce/2; numeros++) {
if (introduce % numeros === 0) {
console.log(numeros," lo divide ");
}
}

Comment: de momento se como hallar los divisores propios en consola pero me falta saber como coger esos valores y sumarlos para que si son menores que el propio numero que meti me de un false

Comment: Favor [edit] y agrega el codigo que acabas de colocar en los comentarios.

Comment: te lo deje en la descripcion gracias

Comment: de ir del mayor hasta cero

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la suma, podrías utilizar una simple variable, en este caso le llame "suma".
Cambié el inicio del ciclo for para que también se pueda sumar el número 1 y modifiqué el final para que se incluya en la suma al número que es la mitad del número ingresado (si es que es entero)

```js
var introduce = prompt("Escribe un número");
var numeros;
var suma=0;

// Si iniciaba en 2 no sumaría el 1
// Si terminaba antes de la mitad de introduce, no sumaría el número que es la mitad de "introduce"
// por ejemplo, en el caso de 16, no sumaría 8.
for (numeros=1; numeros <= introduce/2; numeros++) {
  if (introduce % numeros === 0) {
    suma += numeros;
  }
}

var esDeficiente = suma > 0 && suma<introduce;

console.log("Es Deficiente: " + esDeficiente);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer la cuenta del número que ingresa el usuario, esa misma cuenta dividirla entre el número que ingrese, y validas si el residuo es igual a 0, si lo es insertas esos números en un arreglo, después recorres ese mismo arreglo y sumas los valores y al ultimo haces una condición donde si la suma es menor al número ingresado entonces es deficiente, si no lo es entonces no es deficiente.

```js
let num = prompt('ingresa un numero');

while(isNaN(num) || num == 0){

num = prompt('ingresa un numero');

}

let numeros = [];

for(i = 0; i < num; i++){

if(num % i === 0){
  numeros.push(parseInt(i));

}

}

let suma = 0;

numeros.forEach(function(numero){

suma += numero;

})

console.log(parseInt(suma))

if(suma < num){
console.log(`La suma de los divisibles es ${suma} y es menor a ${num}, por lo tanto el ${num} es deficiente`);

}else{
console.log(`La suma de los divisibles es ${suma} y es mayor a ${num}, por lo tanto el ${num} no es deficiente`);

}
```